# How to sort a part of an array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array having many objects. I am trying to sort the first half of the array with ascending order. And the second half of the array with ascending order too. The code below is an array example and my way to do it. I am thinking is there a smarter way to sharpen the code and get the same result? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
var data = [
    {id:1, x: 33},
    {id:2, x: 22},
    {id:3, x: 11},
    {id:4, x: 3},  
    {id:5, x: 2},
    {id:6, x: 1}  
];
var data1 = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  data1.push(data[i]);
}
data1.sort (function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });

var data2 = [];
for(var i=3; i<6; i++){
  data2.push(data[i]);
}
data2.sort (function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });

data = data1.concat(data2);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: can you tell us how you want to order it? by id or x?

Comment: FYI, you can shorten it a bit by getting rid of the `for` loops, and doing this instead: `var data1 = data.splice(data.length/2);
var data2 = data`

Answer (score 3):

Using splice would tighten it up:

```
var data = [
    {id:1, x: 33},
    {id:2, x: 22},
    {id:3, x: 11},
    {id:4, x: 3},  
    {id:5, x: 2},
    {id:6, x: 1}  
];

// splice out and sort the first half of data
var data1 = data.splice(0,data.length / 2);
data1.sort (function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });

// sort the second half
data.sort (function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });

data = data1.concat(data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: why this `data.splice(1,data.length / 2)` should work in such case ? `console.log(data)` gives the following order of `x` attribute:  `3, 11, 22, 1, 2, 33 `

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, it should.  Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the array with [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and concat with [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
function sortX(a, b) {
    return a.x - b.x;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, x: 33 }, { id: 2, x: 22 }, { id: 3, x: 11 }, { id: 4, x: 3 }, { id: 5, x: 2 }, { id: 6, x: 1 }],
    first = data.slice(0, data.length / 2 | 0).sort(sortX),
    second = data.slice(data.length / 2 | 0, data.length).sort(sortX);

data = first.concat(second);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * This method allows you to split array in two peaces
 * @param Array array - the array which you want to split
 * @returns array
 */
function sort2Array(array) {
    var results = [],
        length = Math.ceil(array.length / 2),
        iterations = array.length / length;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var peace = array.slice(i * length, (i + 1) * length);
        results.push(peace.sort(function(a, b) { return a.x - b.x; }));
    }

    return results[0].concat(results[1]);
}

var data = [
    { id: 1, x: 33 },
    { id: 2, x: 22 },
    { id: 3, x: 11 },
    { id: 4, x: 3 },
    { id: 5, x: 2 },
    { id: 6, x: 1 }
]

sort2Array(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    {id:1, x: 33},
    {id:2, x: 22},
    {id:3, x: 11},
    {id:4, x: 3},  
    {id:5, x: 2},
    {id:6, x: 1}  
];
var sort_fn = function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; };
function half_sort(p) {
    var m = p.length/2;
    return Array.prototype.concat(
      p.slice(0, m).sort(sort_fn),
      p.slice(m).sort(sort_fn) )
}
var result = half_sort(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6

```
let data = [
    {id:1, x: 33},
    {id:2, x: 22},
    {id:3, x: 11},
    {id:4, x: 3},  
    {id:5, x: 2},
    {id:6, x: 1}  
];
const up = data.slice(0,data.length/2).sort((prev,next) => prev.x - next.x);
const low = data.slice(data.length/2,data.length).sort((prev,next) =>  next.x - prev.x);
data = up.concat(low)
```